# Can google dataflow convert an input date to a bigquery timestamp

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, dataflow

quite new to dataflow, I have been searching for days for a solution to my problem. I need to run a pipeline that reads a date from a csv file in the following format : 2019010420300033, passing it through the the different flows and end up in bigquery as a timestamp. Is there a way to do this or the input file must be converter first to a convertible date (I know a format like this works : 2019-01-01 20:30:00.331). 
Or, is is possible to have dataflow output in some way a new pipeline with that date converted?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easy job for Dataflow. You can use either a ParDo or a Map.

In the example below each line from the CSV will be passed to Map(convertDate). The function convertDate, which you need to modify to fit your date conversion, then returns the modified line. Then the entire converted CSV is written to the output file set.

Example (simplified) using Map:

```
def convertDate(line):
    # convert date to desired format
    # Split line into columns, change date format for desired column
    # Rejoin columns into line and return
    cols = line.split(',')  # change for your column seperator
    cols[2] = my_change_method_for_date(cols[2]) # code the date conversion here
    return ",".join(cols)

with beam.Pipeline(argv=pipeline_args) as p:
    lines = p | 'ReadCsvFile' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(args.input)
    lines = lines | 'ConvertDate' >> beam.Map(convertDate)
    lines | 'WriteCsvFile' >> beam.io.WriteToText(args.output)
```

Comment: Thanks i will definitely try this and comment back! It looks like what i was searching for.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a savior! I had to tweek a bit since I had already splitted my fields to a dictionary.
So I did a key value change and it works

def str2timestamp(s, fmt='%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f'):
    dt = datetime.strptime(s, fmt)
    epoch = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
    return (dt - epoch).total_seconds()

line.update({'transaction_date': str2timestamp(line['transaction_date'])})